# How to make linefeed symbol disappear on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, text-editor

I tried to make the little flag-shaped symbol(later I figured, this symbol stands for linefeed) disappear, how do I do that ?

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on:

```
Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors
```

then click the "configure visibility" link. Then uncheck the row Line Feed checkboxes on the subsequent *Show Whitespace Characters* dialog